# Sum of data in a column based on categorical condition from another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df below

```
 df
 Col A   COl B   
  A       25
  A       25
  B       50
  B       50
```

I need below

```
 df1
 ColA    COL B   Sum
  A       25      50 
  A       25      50
  B       50      100
  B       50      100
```

Is there a way?

Comment: Yeah I know the summary function :)  but it creates a new dataset. But I need the sum in this dataset only

Comment: `df$Sum <- ave(df$ColB, df$ColA, FUN = sum)`

Comment: In `dplyr` use `mutate` instead of `summarize`